# No new sms message notifications Sim900

Tags: arduino, sim900

I have problems with the sim900. When I'm reading the serial port and the sim900 module receives a sms. It send an alert via serial port and cause problems with the reading.

I have tried using this command "AT+CNMI=0,0,0,0,0", it works fine if I really don't need sms, but I need them. what can i do if i don't want to receive new sms message notifications when I'm reading the serial port???

Thanks!

Comment: do you want to disable the new sms notifications? or want them?

Comment: Yes, just for a moment.

Answer (score 3):

You may use `AT+CNMI` command to enable or disable **New Message Indication** messages on uart. Keep in mind that you wont get any notification for a message that is received when notifications are disabled so you need to implement a check for it.

You may either delete all existing messages using the `AT+CMGD=1,4` command before disabling the notifications and check for all messages after after resuming notifications or implement any other check.

**TO ENABLE NOTIFICATIONS**    `"AT+CNMI=1,2,0,0,0"`

**TO DISABLE NOTIFICATIONS**    `"AT+CNMI=0,0,0,0,0"`